# Where to get latest fluent nhibernate binary

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Where to find binary for fluent nhibernate. This page is changed now http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/ and i can't find any binary in it.

Is fluent nhibernate still alive and where can i get binary code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest Fluent NHibernate package if you are using NuGet and this is compatible with the latest version of NHibernate (3.3.0.4000).  If you aren't using NuGet I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

You can dowload it with nuget.

http://nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate/1.3.0.717

Comment: thank you very much for that answer. So i just import nhibernate .net and this is it...

Comment: I don't think this is true.  Mapping by code is part of the latest version of NHibernate but that is not Fluent NHibernate.